# Resources to help people learn

Tags: feature-request

I understand that the FAQ makes it clear that questions about learning electrical engineering are off topic.

Is there some way we could have a section or wiki entry with resources to learn?

For example the question "I have a 10 ohm resistor and a current of 1 amp, what is the voltage?" is OK (I think) based upon the FAQ, but "What is a resource I can use to learn ohm's law?" would be off topic. I personally think this is unfortunate as I would like to encourage people to learn. That is why when someone asks us a a question like the former instead of just giving the answer "10 volts" I would like to be able to point them to a wiki page on this site that would help them learn ohm's law.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the difference between making a website that teaches material and a website that is a glorified search results.

"Basic explanation of how to use ohms law with basic applications using resistors?" is a valid technical question that will result in more general knowledge on the internet. As you explain, give links to other technical resources for different topics so that they can learn more. Also take the time to explain what subjects the user might enjoy continuing to as they grow their knowledge base. Maybe complex impedance with some links for where to go?

"Can someone please tell me where I should go to learn more about ohms law?" is invalid, you are already here! We are generating a list of other resources, and especially on the internet the links given will break after time, unlike the above option, these are dead answer instead of being valid answers with reduced support material.

If there are details of what the material is supporting, say you teach about ohms law and give a link to more examples of ohms law another user could choose to update a link and get a different reference easily if your link died.

Comment: Your examples of what would and wouldn't be allowed have the effect of inviting un-researched problems, while discouraging the search for self-help resources.  Surely that can't be the intended net effect.  While we should be open to the completely inexperienced, discouraging people from seeking resources towards finding their own answers can't be right.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, we are here to make the resources. Think of how mant people want to know how to use ohms law. We only have to have one question with a great answer for that. 1 "unresearched" issues solved, all users in the future looking finding an answer on our site. If someone else does not look at all and asks on our site, you can just close as duplicate, no time really wasted.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, you can endlessly ask other resources, and every year when someone asks you will close as duplicate and find that the previous answers become invalid as links die.

Comment: Self help is not confined to web links, it can also incorporate strategies for finding information.  But yes, strategies like links do age, as methods of information presentation change with time. You will never recreate the wealth of online information here, so it's pointless to expect to cover more than the critical small amounts needed to solve problems or trigger discovery of the best available (external) resources at any point in time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, please take a look at stack overflow, they are attempting to find ways to recreate their original success, ie, we follow the stack exchange system. And it is a different question to ask, How do I find resources for this then to ask for resources. They are different, but unless it is an odd topic I do not think teaching others how to find resources is a subject we should spend a large percentage of questions on.